# How is Giza pronounced in Egypt itself?

Tags: factoids, language-barrier, egypt

Over a 100 years ago, I think Giza was pronounced Jeezah. For example, in his multi-volume book on the Great Pyramid, Piazzi Smyth, who worked at Giza for years spelled it "Jeezeh":

[image: label from a map: "map of the Pyramids of Jeezah"]

The image above is from a handdrawn map of the plateau of Giza by Smyth.

Do the Arabs still pronounce it "jeezah", or has the pronounciation changed to "Giza"?

Note, I am asking how it is pronounced locally, not about "academic" pronounciations by people that do not live in the Al Jizah area. In other words I want to know how normal residents of Al Jizah pronounce the name of their neighborhood.

Comment: It's pronounced rather like you described it "jeezuh", accent on the first syllable...

Comment: I'm not convinced enough to flag/close-vote, but isn't this a language question rather than about travel?

Comment: @mts knowing the local city names sounds like travel related to me..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Giza is actually pronounced Jeezah (`الجيزة`) by all Arabs except Egyptians. They pronounce the `J` letter as `G` in their dialect, in time the Latin spelling changed accordingly yet it's still spelled `Jeezah` in Arabic and pronounced correctly by Arabs. Same thing for names as well, for example they pronounce(Jamal) as (Gamal) so they spell it in Latin that way.

Anyway, native southern Egyptians, and native Egyptians in Sinai pronounce it correctly as in classic Arabic and just like the rest of Arabs.

Comment: I've been to Sinai and they pronounced Jungle as Gungle at our hotel :)

Comment: @alamar I am pretty sure the employees are not local to sinai. The locals in Sinai are basically Badu...

Comment: There's a lot of bias here, with your judgements over which dialect is "correct" and which is not!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit technically the sound G doesn't exist in Arabic and is only present in Egyptian spoken dialect, so the "correct" pronunciation **is** actually J. Obviously millions of Egyptians say G, academics aren't so important

Comment: @blackbird: By definition, then, it obviously does exist: in Egyptian Arabic! This makes it perfectly "correct".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's a bit more complicated that that, spoken and written Arabic can differ quite a bit. G exists in dialect, but not in the formal, written language. But it doesn't matter, because people use it and language is alive

Comment: @lightness I compared to classic Arabic. All dialects pronounce it as classic Arabic except Egyptians. Other dialects pronounce some other letters incorrectly while Egyptians do pronounce it correctly. Not being bias here whatsoever. If the question was about pronouncing "S" instead of "TH" is western Saudi, I would say that it's wrong, as I personally do in my dialect.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis: "Other"/"classic" != "Correct" :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok whatever, you are the boss.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis: Indeed :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you need to understand that your culture is different than mine, and your language is different than mine, and in Arabic we consider the classic arabic as CORRECT and the dialects are not correct, we do not write dialects and we write classic... that's us,  so next time try to think that there are other cultures and other life style beside yours before trying to force your own opinion or thinking of other cultures or languages as your own. I'd appreciate that a lot.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis: In other words: "it is in my culture and lifestyle to be belittling and intolerant towards speakers of related languages, so you can't call me out on my intolerance". Lovely.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis: Read back what you just said to me, because it's 100% hypocritical, and that was my entire point.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's either your way, or no way.. ok boss :)

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis: No, that's what _you_ are saying to the Egyptians!!

Comment: @HenningMakholm & LIRO, you're missing NeanDerThal's point: in the same way that English has generally agreed standard spelling and it's "wrong" to misspell words in formal contexts (say, business writing), Arabic has generally agreed standard pronunciation and *in formal contexts* (say, reciting the Quran) it's "wrong" to use another pronunciation.  It's not a value judgement, because *nobody speaks classical Arabic*, in the same way English uses Latinate spelling despite there being no Latin speakers around anymore!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "with your judgements over which dialect is 'correct' and which is not" - unlike English, some languages or countries indeed have governing bodies that define what is or is not "correct" in terms of orthography, word meaning, and pronunciation. Typically, that does not prevent or even attempt to deter people from using their language differently (as a dialect), but is meant to indicate what can reliably be called "correct" and used as such in official or legally relevant contexts.

Answer (score 11):

This is the most obvious difference between the Egyptian Arabic dialect and the standard Arabic, the 'Jeem' letter `ج` . It's 'Geem' In most of Egypt.

But since this is not a question about grammar, and you just ask about how it's pronounced in Egypt, the answer is

> Giza is pronounced **Giza** by 100% of Giza local people. It is not "Jeezah"

---

And if you are interested in more details,

- It's **Giza** in **all** of Egypt cities including ([Giza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giza), [Cairo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo), [Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandria), [Port Said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Said),.... ) and except of the cities in number 2
- It's **Jeezah** in [Upper Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Egypt), [Sharqia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharqia_Governorate), [Sinai Peninsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinai_Peninsula)
- [Sharm El-Sheikh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharm_El_Sheikh) Is in Sinai Peninsula, however it's  a mixed city full of tourists and people from different Egyptian cities, so I think I can't be definitely sure.
- All other Arab countries say **"Jeezah"** .

*I don't think you really need to pronounce it as the local Giza citizens do when you are there!. If you looked like a tourist, then any difference will be understood by the people you are interacting with.*